# Add Nodes with attributes from a .txt file with multiple delimiters networkx/pandas

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, edges

I have a `.txt` File that has 46 lines, each line stands for a node in a network and then has LOTS of attributes behind it.

```
Example Name; 03.01.194, Luzern, (LU), Test, Attribute, Other Attribute, 
Kasdasd Alex; 22.12.1957, in Blabla, (ZH), Bürgerorte, Oeschgen (AG),  Zivilstand,
```

I'm not sure how I get networkx to see this as a nodelist, some things I thought about, that maybe could work, but do not at the moment

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
nodes = pd.read_csv('final.csv', header=None)
nodes
```

Problem with the code above is that the attributes are separated by commas, but not the nodes.

Another try, where I wanted to open the file, and add nodes line by line but got stuck on the  `G.add_node()` command

```
G = nx.Graph()
with open('final.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        G.add_node()
```

Is one of the two the approach to go for or should I try something different?

Also for further analysis, does networkx offer a possibilty to compare attributes of nodes and if they match, create a weighted edge?

Comment: Copy and past first few lines of txt/csv file pls

Comment: added a second line, they all look like this

Comment: `Example Name; ` is the only node in line

Comment: thats the point `Example Name;` should be the node and the rest behind it the attributes of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by reading the file specifying the delimiter as ';' so that the first element is the node key and the rest are the attributes. Then split the attributes string with the delimiter ',' and add the returned list as a node attribute. I copied the sample you provided in 'test.txt' file and executed the following code.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()

csv_F = csv.reader(open("test.txt"),delimiter=';')
for row in csv_F:
    attributes=row[1].split(',')
    G.add_node(row[0], attr = attributes)
```

Then I printed the nodes and their attributes as follows:

```
for n in G.nodes():
    print 'Node: '  + str(n)
    print 'Atrributes' + str(G.node[n]['attr'])
```

Result:

> Node: Kasdasd Alex
>
> Atrributes: [' 22.12.1957', ' in Blabla', ' (ZH)', ' B\xc3\xbcrgerorte', ' Oeschgen (AG)', '  Zivilstand', '']
>
> Node: Example Name
>
> Atrributes: [' 03.01.194', ' Luzern', ' (LU)', ' Test', ' Attribute', ' Other Attribute', ' ']

As for your question in the end, networkx offers such capabilities and more. Have a look on the tutorial [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/tutorial/index.html).